# cakephp 2.x edit field for comparing old and new records

Tags: php, cakephp, edit

Question : I want to compare the different records before and after edit.

1)  i find that it will generate different id to get the corresponding fields  ***** $this->set( compact('brands', 'imageTypes')); *****

and auto write into view's fields. But how can i get all input field names    ( I want to auto find all the fields record by these two id automatically in case there are some fields change in the future. )

Controller :

```
   function admin_edit(){

    $this->BrandImage->id = $id;
        if (!$this->BrandImage->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid brand image'));
        }


        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {


            if ($this->BrandImage->save($this->request->data)) {


//                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The brand image has been saved'), 'flash/success');
//              $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The brand image could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash/error');
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('BrandImage.' . $this->BrandImage->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->BrandImage->find('first', $options);

            debug( $this->request->data['BrandImage']['path']);

        }
        $brands = $this->BrandImage->Brand->find('list');
        $imageTypes = $this->BrandImage->ImageType->find('list');
        $this->set( compact('brands', 'imageTypes'));
     }
```

Comment: who can help11111

Comment: I'd suggest that you try to reword your question, and come up with a code example that illustrates what you're trying to do, as I really don't understand what you are talking about, and I guess others will feel the same (no offense).